# Quotients and associated graded

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, associated-graded

$\DeclareMathOperator\gr{gr}$Let $A = \cup_{i=0}^\infty F_i A$ be a filtered commutative ring, $I \subseteq A$ an ideal. Then we have a canonical surjection
$$ \gr(A)/\gr(I) \to \gr(A/I).$$
Under what conditions is this surjection an isomorphism?

I most wish to know about the following special case: $A = \mathbb C[z_1,\ldots, z_n]$ equipped with the total degree filtration, $I$ an ideal of finite codimension. The ring $\gr(A/I)$ in this case should be functions on the scheme "$\lim_{t \to 0} t\cdot V(I)$", and I'd like to know when the defining ideal is $gr(I)$.

Comment: Is $I$ graded too?

Comment: @Mohan No, there is no grading on $I$. $I$ is filtered by $F_i I = I \cap F_i A$.

Comment: I don't know whether I am mistaken, but this seems always true? More generally, it seems that the associated graded modules of a strict exact sequence of filtered modules constitute a short exact sequence, with the following argument: a strict exact sequence of filtered modules gives rise to a short exact sequence of Rees modules (whose graded pieces are given by the filtration), and apply the snake lemma to get a short exact sequence of associated graded modules being the cokernel of a canonical map of Rees modules, properly shifted.

Comment: @Z.M Thank you. I have elaborated on your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow user @Z. M's comment.

If $M = \cup_{i=0}^\infty F_i M$ is a filtered module and
$$0 \to M' \to M \to M'' \to 0$$
is a short exact sequence such that $M', M''$ have the *induced filtrations*, then we get a short exact sequence of Rees modules
$$0 \to R_hM' \to R_hM \to R_hM'' \to 0,$$
which yields the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathrm{gr}(M') \to \mathrm{gr}(M) \to \mathrm{gr}(M'') \to 0$ after taking the Snake Lemma (since our filtration is by submodules).

Now in our situation, $A/I$ and $I$ have the induced filtrations, so we get a short exact sequence
$ 0 \to \mathrm{gr}(I) \to \mathrm{gr}(A) \to \mathrm{gr}(A/I) \to 0$.